# Navigation drawer back from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, fragmenttransaction

I am using this navigation drawer tutorial to build my application [Android hive navigation drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/), i have added fragment to it say there is a button in fragment 1 when i click it i navigate to fragment 2 when i press back i am supposed to go back to fragment 1 but what happens is that the application gets closed, i have tried this but it didn't work

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                    Fragment fragment = new ListOfStudentsFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentTAG");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
```

Comment: add code of both fragment 1 to 2 and fragment 2 to 1.

Comment: would like to see back press event of fragment too

Comment: i am sorry i am totally new to this, am i supposed to implement back press in the second fragment?! in android developer it says **By calling addToBackStack(), the replace transaction is saved to the back stack so the user can reverse the transaction and bring back the previous fragment by pressing the Back button.** @Keshav1234 @ Bhavik Mehta

Comment: Use Fragment **popBackStack()** or **popBackStackImmediate()**